# findAndModify not using index search

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using python (pymongo) with mogno 4.2

My DB contains around 1M docs
, a sample from the DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02"),
    "my_id" : "1",
    "data": {
        "status": "new"
    }
}
```

I created two indexes, one for "my_id" and the second for "data.status" fields.

In my code I do a simple find_one_and_update that use only indexed field:

```
document = collection.find_one_and_update(
            filter={
                "$and": [
                    {"data.status": "new"},
                    {"_id": ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02")},
                ]
            },
            update={
                "$set": {
                    "data": {
                        "status": "in_progress",
                        "last_update": datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                        "other_data": data
                     }
                }
            }
        )
```

running this on production under full scale causes COLLSCAN and not IXSCAN.
but running it manualy from robo3t the operation is IXSCAN.

my question is, why mogno is not using my index?

EDIT:

Here is an output from the system profile for the operation happaning in production-

```
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "db.collection",
    "command" : {
        "findAndModify" : "collection",
        "query" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "data.status" : "new"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02")
                }
            ]
        },
        "new" : false,
        "update" : {
            "$set" : {
                "data" : {
                    "status" : "in_progress",
                    "last_update" : ISODate("2020-07-30T14:16:23.290Z")
                }
            }
        },
        "sort" : {
            "$natural" : 1
        },
        "upsert" : false,
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("opkrstuv-abcd-1234-efgh-5678ijkl90mn")
        },
        "$db" : "db",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primary"
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 902501,
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nModified" : 1,
    "keysInserted" : 1,
    "keysDeleted" : 1,
    "numYield" : 7090,
    "queryHash" : "AAAAAAAA",
    "planCacheKey" : "BBBBBBBB",
    "locks" : {
        "ParallelBatchWriterMode" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(7092)
            }
        },
        "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(7092)
            }
        },
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                "w" : NumberLong(7091)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(7091)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(7091)
            }
        },
        "Mutex" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        }
    },
    "flowControl" : {
        "acquireCount" : NumberLong(7091),
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : NumberLong(1799)
    },
    "storage" : {},
    "responseLength" : 168,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 24746,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "UPDATE",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4009,
        "works" : 902502,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 902501,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 7090,
        "restoreState" : 7090,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "nMatched" : 1,
        "nWouldModify" : 1,
        "wouldInsert" : false,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3766,
            "works" : 902502,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 902501,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 7091,
            "restoreState" : 7091,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "limitAmount" : 1,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : {
                                "$eq" : ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02")
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data.status" : {
                                "$eq" : "new"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3726,
                "works" : 902502,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 902501,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 7091,
                "restoreState" : 7091,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "docsExamined" : 902501
            }
        }
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2020-07-30T14:16:48.069Z"),
    "client" : "256.256.256.256",
    "allUsers" : [],
    "user" : ""
}
```

and here is the output of the `.explain()` I run manualy from 3T-

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "db.collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02")
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "data.status" : {
                        "$eq" : "new"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "UPDATE",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "data.status" : {
                        "$eq" : "new"
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "_id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "_id" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : true,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [ 
                            "[ObjectId('5f41983da09c453f96cebf02'), ObjectId('5f41983da09c453f96cebf02')]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "UPDATE",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 2,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "nMatched" : 1,
            "nWouldModify" : 1,
            "wouldInsert" : false,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "data.status" : {
                        "$eq" : "new"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 1,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 1,
                "restoreState" : 1,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 1,
                    "advanced" : 1,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1,
                    "restoreState" : 1,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "_id_",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "_id" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : true,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "_id" : [ 
                            "[ObjectId('5f41983da09c453f96cebf02'), ObjectId('5f41983da09c453f96cebf02')]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 1,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "host",
        "port" : 00000,
        "version" : "4.2.8",
        "gitVersion" : "1"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the `getIndexes()` output-

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "my_id" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "my_id_1",
        "ns" : "db.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "data.status" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "data.status_1",
        "ns" : "db.collection"
    }
]
```

THANKS!

Comment: Is this your real query? You have always an index on `_id`, index on `data.status` would be useless. I wonder why it is not used.

Comment: data.status is a field that ensures that nor two workers updating the same document.

Comment: Check whether indices are created properly in production. Update oollscan on what column? can you add complete explain output both on prod and local?

Comment: @Gibbs I've edited the post and added the outputs, Thanks.
and I'm using tunnel from local so it's actually the same db, so same indexes.

Comment: I'm curious why you have the `$and` construct in the filter rather than just using `filter={"data.status": "new","_id": ObjectId("5f41983da09c453f96cebf02")}`

Comment: @BellyBuster I've a query builder that manage all the different queries, $and is just a side effect of code simplicity.

Comment: Ok, well there's a chance that might be having an impact.

Comment: @BellyBuster thanks for the suggestion! I just tried but query without $and had the same outcome.

Comment: Can you include the output of `getIndexes()` and your query with `.explain()`? It should give us some more information on what's happening.

Comment: @Plancke I've added to the post the `getIndexes()` output, an `.explain()` output is already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Apparently I missed the fact that my python code added by default a **sort** by `$neutral`, so the sorting actually got the winningPlan and so ignored the indexes.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help!